# Remove the SharePoint-Hosted App standard "Page Title & Navigation"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to remove this clickable image and top-bar navigation that comes by default when creating a SharePoint-Hosted App, how do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is coming from a master page. The master page `url` can be found in `Default.aspx`. So add some custom css rules to hide top-bar navigation. When you create a SharePoint hosted app by default master page is added.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
```

**Solution 1:** You can add some css to maser page (Recommended)

**Solution 2:** Add your css inside default page

I just opened my SharePoint Online site and following style will hide top-bar

```
#suiteBar{
    display: none;
}
```

Following code will hide title and related things. Inspect in `titleAreaBox` element and hide what you need.

```
#titleAreaBox{
  display: none;
}

#s4-ribbonrow{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete custom landing page, create a html/ blank aspx page and use it as the home page in `app.manifest`. That would give you an entirely clean slate to work on.

See this [discussion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115937/html-page-as-default-page-of-sharepoint-hosted-app) for changing the default page

Comment: comments will be appreciated in case of a downvote ...